# Image segmentation with edgeTPU

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow-lite

I´m new here, so please be kind and teach me if I did not provide all the information you need :)

I would like to compare Edge TPU with other edge device such as Myriad. I would like to select one object detection model and one image segmentation model. Considering the following link which shows supported operations, I have noticed that yolov3 cannot be compiled for EdgeTPU because it includes LeakyRelu.

https://coral.withgoogle.com/docs/edgetpu/models-intro/

For image segmentation, I'd like to use Deeplab. But I'm still don't know if operations included in deeplab v3+, such as atrous convolution or feature pyramid network, are supported.

I'd appreciate if someone teach me what models are usable on edgeTPU. Are there any models of image segmentation?

Answer (score 0):

Did you already found below?
https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/deeplab/g3doc/quantize.md

"mobilenetv2_coco_voc_trainaug_8bit":

deeplabv3_mnv2_pascal_train_aug_8bit/frozen_inference_graph.pb

This model is possible to converting to TFLite FlatBuffer.
And also possible to compile for edgetpu with edgetpu_compiler.

Note. edgetpu_api environment had updated.
You can find it below.
https://coral.withgoogle.com/news/updates-07-2019/

Answer (score 0):

Yes. There are prepackaged segmentation models and code examples how to use them.
Here they are https://coral.ai/models/
Please share if you know where to find something similar for Movidius based VPU devices.

Comment: Hi, please include the most relevant info in your answer because a link may expire

Answer (score 0):

Here you can find all supported layers for edgetpu: https://coral.ai/docs/edgetpu/models-intro/#supported-operations.

And for Conv2D it says "Must use the same dilation in x and y dimensions.". So implementing a version of deeplab v3+ is possible for the edgetpu.